# When to implement `Zero` member in Computation Expression?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, monads, computation-expression

Why can't I use `pattern matching function` in computation expressions without implement `Zero` member?

For example, could somepone explain why it permits allowing `pattern matching expression` but not `pattern matching function`?

```
type MaybeBuilder() =
    member __.Bind (x, f) = match x with Some a -> f a | None -> None
    member __.Return x = Some x

let maybe = MaybeBuilder()

// Errors: FS0708 This control construct may only be used
// if the computation expression builder defines a 'Zero' method
maybe { Some 1 |> function Some x -> return x | None -> return 0 }
maybe { Some 1 |> fun x -> match x with Some x' -> return x' | None -> return 0 }

// Ok
maybe { match Some 1 with Some x -> return x | None -> return 0 }
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing a `Zero` method and seeing what happens?  I expect you'll be surprised - the problem is likely not what you're expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error seems to be an effect of a subtle issue with your example. When you write `maybe { Some 1 |> function Some x -> return x | None -> return 0 }`, it's equivalent to the following code

```
let expr1 = function Some x -> return x | None -> return 0
let expr2 = Some 1 |> expr1

maybe { expr2 }
```

which shows that

1. you aren't calling `return` for the result of `expr2`, so the compiler can only guess that is what you want, and asks for `Zero()` method to give the value of the result of `maybe { expr2 }`, and
2. the `return` calls that you have there are used in a wrong scope (and if you split your code like this, compiler will complain) so even if you implement `Zero()`, it won't compile.

To fix that, you can rewrite the functions as

```
maybe { return Some 1 |> function Some x -> x | None -> 0 }
```

or you can add the `maybe` computation expression inside the branches of `expr1` function. It looks bad in this example, but may be viable for more complicated logic that may not all be in the context of `maybe { }` builder

```
Some 1 |> function Some x -> maybe { return x } | None -> maybe { return 0 }
```